# Mount Windows 2016 Share to Ubuntu 20.0.4

Tags: mount, windows, directory

I am trying to mount two Windows shared folders from the Windows 2012R2 Standard server and the Windows 2016 Standard server to the Ubuntu 20.0.4 server.

The Linux Server successfully mount the windows 2012 server folder but not the Windows 2016 folder.

The Windows 2016 folder gives a mount error:

```
CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation. 
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
```

The Mounts use same Active directory Service account credential.
The Windows servers are in the same subnet, and registered in the same Active Directory Domain.

The Linux box is behind the firewall, and all required ports are open.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could be the SMB version number?  I had similar years ago with Centos and had to force version 1.

Comment: In general, error -2 is a permission error. Use the terminal command `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"` or some variant, to see the system logs. They'll have more information.

Comment: I'll suggest applying security fixes to your machine asap, as 20.04.4 shows you've not been applying them. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/09/01/ubuntu-20-04-5-lts-released/ will show the ISO release date of 20.04.5, but installed systems upgraded in the weeks before that date. Your lack of upgrading may also be involved in your issue.